# Loading new content into a responsive slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How does this slider reload new content as the page is resized?

http://www.herschelsupply.com/

I stumbled across this whilst shopping and their slider is a good facsimile of what I want to create for my own site. Their slider loads new content at a certain point when the window is resized. I have had troubles doing that using BxSlider because I am new to JS.

---

More info

The problems I have had are these:

1. I can use css media query or jQuery to hide certain slides, but they remain in the DOM so the slider still displays them in the pager and sometimes it just stops rotating/breaks.
2. If I create two different sliders to be loaded at different widths the change does not occur as the page is resized. Also this seems wasteful.
3. If I remove and replace elements from the DOM on $(window).resize(), I am not sure how to return them to the DOM if the window is resized back and forth continuously.

---

Overall I am just asking what approach you would take to do this? Im sorry if this is verging more towards discussion than a specific question, but I'm not sure where else to ask.

Comment: Concerning problem 1: what if you use media queries just to replace images in slides?  Concerning problem 2: I agree.  Concerning problem 3: you could save the dom elements and cache them at page load, so it wouldn't take a lot of processing to add and remove them.

Comment: I don't see that it is loading new content as the page is resized, it has 6 slides no matter the width.  Moreover, why would you want to load more/less content based on the window size? If it's important at a wide/narrow screen, wouldn't it be important at a wide/narrow screen?

Comment: Erik - thankyou for feedback, will think about your points and respond. Chris - the images are actually different, as there are a set for large and a set for small (they are just visually the same). The problem with only having one set of images I have found is that when they resize down their height becomes too narrow. So their smaller set of images have different ratios (they are squarer) to be better viewed on narrower screens.

Comment: There are actually two different sliders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website you showed simply has two completely separate slideshows.  One is hidden and another is shown when the window resizes.

```
<div id="slider-one" class="hide-for-mobile">
/*Slider here*/
</div>

<div id="slider-two" class="show-for-mobile">
/*Slider here*/
</div>
```

Then in your media query for mobile...

```
.hide-for-mobile {
display: none;
}

.show-for-mobile {
display: block;
}
```

Now, as for a solution that's more along the lines of what you were trying to do...  What you need to do is get away from HTML `<img>` tags.  Instead, your sliding elements should be `<div>`'s with a CSS background image.  In this way, in your media queries you can change the background image of the `<div>`'s.  I am unsure whether or not the slider you are using can support this, some are dependent on sliding an actual HTML `<img>` tag.  Some can slide whatever you want.  You should be able to manage what I've described with Flexslider (a quick google search will get you where you need to be).

Comment: Thank-you, also having looked a bit closer now I see you are right. Sorry I should probably better investigated first. Anyway, do you think that approach is inefficient?

Comment: @Sirrah There are various pro's and con's.  I just edited my answer above with a solution more in line with what you were trying to do.  The problem with my approach above is that you lose any SEO benefit you might have had with the images alt="" tags.  On the other hand, if you are using div's to slide, you can easily include a <p> tag to describe the slide like you would with an alt="" tag and then simply hide that paragraph from view using something like text-indent: -999em;  It also depends on what kind of site you are building...

Comment: Re: your suggestions, I tried the div method with BxSlider and I couldn't get it to work, which is a shame. I appreciate the suggestion of flexslider! I am just messing around/learning at this stage, so SEO isn't problematic.

Comment: @Sirrah Flexslider should work fine for you, it has the ability to add "captions" via a specific class which can be put onto almost any tag, including a div.  In this way you can use the "caption" div's as your images, and put any relevant seo info into headings/paragraphs that then are hidden off-screen.  (unless you want the caption text to appear which is certainly fine also)